# how can I setup virtual repository in Sonatype nexus oss 3

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus

I install unzip plugin following the instructions in my nexus oss 3, but I don't have an optional to add virtual repository 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin
[image]

Comment: That plugin is compatible with Nexus Repo 2.x, it won't work in Nexus Repo 3.x

Answer (score 2):

What Artifactory calls a virtual repository, Nexus calls a repository group.